# Paypal Express checkout button is not working after switch to product mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

I'm using Paypal Express checkout button on my website.

It works well on sandbox mode. 
But after switch to production mode with production key, it doesn't work.

Always returns invalid_client errors.

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}
```

I tried to change Paypal App key several times, but always failed.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33823954/5734311

Comment: @ChrisG
That is for backend Node.js development. I'm using checkout button on the frontend, and the possible env mode are 'sandbox' and 'production' in the official document.

Comment: For such issues you need to share minimum and relevant code for us to help you with the solution