# PayPal SDK Rest Api

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to switch from sandbox to live but on sandbox I get 0 errors and it works but on live. I keep getting this error:

> {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication
>   failed"}

Even though my account is a business account and everything is approved. 
.Mode is already set to live

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PayPal Client Authentication Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815079/paypal-client-authentication-failed)

Comment: Mode is already set to live